# Hiding Search Results Office 365

Tags: list, search, office-365, configuration

I am trying to hide search results for certain posts in a discussion board app from appearing in the search.

Is this possible?

I have added the field "Private" a yes/no field to the discussions.

Some entries can appear and others can not depending on if the private field is no for that discussion or yes.

Does anyone know how to do this.

Comment: No solution to the actual question, but only restricting search to pick up certain items when users can navigate to the content and see it seems like a confusing thing to do. Have you thought about using another discussion list where only the people with "access" have read+ rights?

Comment: how do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

A better practice is to secure the content that you want private. This will prevent unauthorized access AND remove it from search results for unauthorized users.

Comment: Some information / basic steps on how to do that will make this answer even more awesome ;)